# PHP regex get all images from javascript var

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I need to get all images from this javascript,  tried many regex but never working well:

```
<script>
    var images = new Array(), images_thumbs = new Array();
    images_thumbs[0] = "//domain.com/thumbs/c7d/c7dfc634711bc658243aa7575b048b5d4f72fb6d.jpg"; 
    images[0] = "//domain.com/xxl/c7d/c7dfc634711bc658243aa7575b048b5d4f72fb6d.jpg";

    images_thumbs[1] = "//img4.leboncoin.fr/thumbs/222/222d9946df4466e3ecdc3c17ea96bffe0b6bb739.jpg"; 
    images[1] = "//img4.leboncoin.fr/xxl/222/222d9946df4466e3ecdc3c17ea96bffe0b6bb739.jpg";

    images_thumbs[2] = "//img1.leboncoin.fr/thumbs/361/361ea09124fde43162f6e638137aa1032f563654.jpg"; 
    images[2] = "//img1.leboncoin.fr/xxl/361/361ea09124fde43162f6e638137aa1032f563654.jpg";
</script>
```

I tried

```
$sPattern = "/images(*?);/s";
preg_match_all($sPattern,$webpage,$aMatch);
print_r($aMatch);
```

But not working

Comment: *Compilation failed: nothing to repeat* - right?

Comment: Is this script available to you as a string? Can't you directly access `images` variable in javascript?

Comment: I grab webpage with php curl, I want to extract images url and download

Comment: It should be `(.*?)`

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/xI1zV1/1 Have a look here. That is assuming you only want images and not the thumbnails.

Comment: Your question is a little ambiguous, can you give an example of the expected outcome, i.e what you want as a result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afk for the rest of the day so submitting something that might help.

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
preg_match_all('/\/\/(.*.jpg)/', $str, $results);
var_dump($results);

array(6) {
    [0]=> string(68) "//domain.com/thumbs/c7d/c7dfc634711bc658243aa7575b048b5d4f72fb6d.jpg"
    [1]=> string(65) "//domain.com/xxl/c7d/c7dfc634711bc658243aa7575b048b5d4f72fb6d.jpg"
    [2]=> string(75) "//img4.leboncoin.fr/thumbs/222/222d9946df4466e3ecdc3c17ea96bffe0b6bb739.jpg"
    [3]=> string(72) "//img4.leboncoin.fr/xxl/222/222d9946df4466e3ecdc3c17ea96bffe0b6bb739.jpg"
    [4]=> string(75) "//img1.leboncoin.fr/thumbs/361/361ea09124fde43162f6e638137aa1032f563654.jpg"
    [5]=> string(72) "//img1.leboncoin.fr/xxl/361/361ea09124fde43162f6e638137aa1032f563654.jpg"
}
```

This is based on getting all of the images, as opposed to say just the large versions.

[3v4l.org example](https://3v4l.org/pubA2)